# How cookies are handled if you use a proxy between a client and server in HTTP

Tags: cookies, proxy, client

How cookies are handled if you use a proxy between a client and server in HTTP

Comment: possible duplicate of [How cookies are handled if you use a proxy between a client and server in HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662409/how-cookies-are-handled-if-you-use-a-proxy-between-a-client-and-server-in-http)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are just sent as extra HTTP headers; the proxy server passes them through like any other data