# How cookies are handled if you use a proxy between a client and server in HTTP

Tags: cookies

How cookies are handled if you use a proxy between a client and server in HTTP

Answer (score 4):

There is no particular issue with cookies. The `Cookie` request and `Set-Cookie` response headers are passed straight through proxies.

If you are worried about a page that depends on a cookie being cached by a proxy and served to a different user who shouldn't be able to see it, you should specify this case with the header:

```
Cache-Control: private
```

This should be done for any pages protected by a cookie-based login system.

Answer (score 2):

The proxy proxies them, just like it proxies everything else.